# $index orderby in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, indexing, sql-order-by

i have created jsfiddle for my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/CeNyg/1/

```
<div ng-repeat="char in blockCharJson" row="{{char.row}}" column="{{char.column}}" >{{char.id}}</div>


var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.blockCharJson = {};
    console.log($scope.blockCharJson);
    for(var i=0; i<16; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<16; j++ ){
            $scope.blockCharJson[i*16+j] = {id:i*16+j, row:i, column:j }
        }
    }
});
```

now tell me what should i do to order elements from 0 to 255..
because  it by default takes 10 after 1...i dont know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead of an object: http://jsfiddle.net/CeNyg/2/

Basically an object `{}` does not have a guaranteed order of items, where as an array `[]` does. After creating the array:

`$scope.blockCharJson = [];`,

you can add items to the end of the array via the `push` function. For example:

`$scope.blockCharJson.push({id:i*16+j, row:i, column:j });`